# Social Share Buttons like CNET

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, social-networking

a while back, CNET had these really cool Social Share buttons, that when you click on it, a "dropdown box" appeared with the social networks share dialog.

Does anyone has any idea how the made that ? As I couldn't find anything on this, and their website had been updated ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ready made options out there:

http://www.addthis.com 
http://www.sharethis.com

Which might be what you're after

Comment: thanks for the try, but as I said, I was looking for the old "popover" style sharing

Comment: Hi, found it on the facebook site for sharer